# have added @Tansactional, but rollback is still not happening when explicitly throwing a checked exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Transactional(value="txManager", rollbackFor = DriverReassignmentException.class)
    public UserLoadAssocResponse<List<AssociateResponse>, UserLoadAssocResponseStatus> reassignAssignedLoad(String user, String scac, String adminId, DriverLoadAssocDetails driverLoadAssocDetails) throws DriverReassignmentException{

        UserLoadAssocResponse<Boolean, UserLoadAssocResponseStatus> removeUserResponse =null;

        UserLoadAssocResponse<List<AssociateResponse>, UserLoadAssocResponseStatus> userLoadAssignedResponse=null;

        if(!(StringUtils.isEmpty(driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber()) && StringUtils.isEmpty(user) && StringUtils.isEmpty(scac) && StringUtils.isEmpty(adminId))){
            try {
                removeUserResponse = this.userLoadAssociationClient.removeUserFromAssignedLoad(user, scac, driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber(),adminId, Constant.INTRANSIT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                removeUserResponse = UserLoadAssocResponse.failure(UserLoadAssocResponseStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR);
                log.error("Unable to remove user {} from load {} scac: {} adminUser: {} admin", user, driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber(), scac, adminId, e);
            }
        } else{
            log.error("Insufficient data present to remove user {} from load {} scac: {} adminUser: {} admin", user, driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber()!=null?driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber():null, scac, adminId);
            return UserLoadAssocResponse.failure(UserLoadAssocResponseStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR);

        }

        if(removeUserResponse.isSuccess() && removeUserResponse.getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(UserLoadAssocResponseStatus.SUCCESS.toString())){
            try {
                userLoadAssignedResponse = this.associateSingleUserSingleLoad(scac, adminId, driverLoadAssocDetails);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.error("Unexpected error occured while assigning single load for carrierCode {} - {}", scac, ex);
                throw new DriverReassignmentException(UserLoadAssocResponseStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR.name());
            }
        }else{
            return UserLoadAssocResponse.failure(removeUserResponse.getStatus());
        }

        if(userLoadAssignedResponse.isSuccess() && userLoadAssignedResponse.getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(UserLoadAssocResponseStatus.SUCCESS.toString())){
            log.info("Load reassigned succesfully:{}", userLoadAssignedResponse);
            return userLoadAssignedResponse;
        }else{
            log.error("Error occured while assigning single load for carrierCode {}", scac);
            throw new DriverReassignmentException("Load reassigned Unsuccesfull");

        }

    }
```

```
// expecting to rollback this.userLoadAssociationClient.removeUserFromAssignedLoad(user, scac, driverLoadAssocDetails.getOrderNumber(),adminId, Constant.INTRANSIT)
```

when `throw new DriverReassignmentException("Load reassigned Unsuccesfull")` is thrown. But not being bale to achieve

Comment: If I understand the code flow correctly , you are returning with `return UserLoadAssocResponse.failure(removeUserResponse.getStatus());`  when `userLoadAssignedResponse` is not successful , isn't it ? That case , the code to raise exception will never be reached.

Comment: And it should rollback because? What is the `userLoadAssociationClient` is that a webservice, rest, direct db access, what is it? Does that manage its own transactin? Also which database are you using (if you are using MySQL make sure you are using InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables!).

Comment: Is transactional method invoked from other bean? or from other method in same class?

Comment: How do you call the method? And assuming it is part of a class C, how do you instantiate C?

Comment: @M.Deinum **userLoadAssociationClient** is a webservice call and it is using Mysql. It manages its own transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to rollback the userLoadAssociationClient webservice call if any exception is thrown by **associateSingleUserSingleLoad** or the response status from **associateSingleUserSingleLoad** webservice call is not matching to be success

Comment: @RafałSurowiecki have added more details to my clarification

Comment: @FrankHopkins have added more details to my clarification

Comment: You cannot rollback a webservice call, that is not how transactions work.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible real Error

Remove the return statement in the following line:

```
return UserLoadAssocResponse.failure
```

I think you are returning from the method without evaluating the if condition that would throw the proper exception.

### Additional Debugging

You have an error in your logic. The best way to really debug whether your transactional annotation is working is to add the following line as the last line of your method **BUT without the `if` statement**

```
throw new DriverReassignmentException("Load reassigned Unsuccessful");
```

Then you will be able to evaluare if the rollback is happenning because you will know that for every request, you are throwing the specific exception.

Then, comment out the `throws` and you should notice that your data is saved, and no exception happens.

The problem is in the conditions of the `if statement`. You need to debug the logic and see why your `if statement` is not evaluating to true.

Comment: I tried just to throw   **DriverReassignmentException("Load reassigned Unsuccessful")** commenting all the conditional check but still no luck on that. DriverReassignmentException is a checked exception. Is this is because of calling another webservice

Comment: I want to rollback the userLoadAssociationClient webservice call if any exception is thrown by **associateSingleUserSingleLoad** or the response status from **associateSingleUserSingleLoad** webservice call is not matching to be success

Answer (score 0):

I've asked for clarification on how you call the method because one easy mistake in a Spring(Boot) based setup is a misunderstanding in how @Transactional works.

In particular, given the default settings, **the @Transactional annotation only works when the instance of the class with the annotated method that is called has been instantiated via Spring and is called via Spring and not directly from another method in the same class.**

Typically that would mean you have an instance

```
@Autowired
CoolClass classInstance;
```

and then you go with

```
classInstance.transactionalMethod
```

where that method is annotation with @Transactional

```
@Transactional
public void transactionalMethod(...){
```

If you instead call

```
classInstance.someOtherMethod()
```

where

```
public void someOtherMethod(){
  this.transactionalMethod(...);
}
```

it would not work.

Similarly, if you create your class manually like this:

```
CoolClass classInstance=new CoolClass(..);
```

if will also not work.

This is because of how Spring in the default settings supports @Transactional. 
This behaviour can be changed by switching the transaction manager to the AspectJ weaving mode (see here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

In summary, for the @Transactional annotation to work properly with default proxy mode:

1. the method needs to be public
2. the call must come from outside of the (spring managed) bean

(And that my dear friends is why Spring's @Transactional annotation is a nice little booby trap - looks nice innocent and awesome, but can seriously burn you by silently letting you down.)

Comment: This was pretty helpful .  But what i learnt is that for a distributed microservice architecture different transactional changes cannot be handled by adding @transactional. Found some other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: That depends on the level of transaction safety that is required. Operations spread over multiple microservices cannot be made transactional by the annotation, individual operations by one microservice can very well be made 'safe' by being made transactional. Still, nice that you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help